# Java Installation In Cent OS shows Only JRE (Jdk is NOT shown under Java but in JRE folder)

Tags: java

I have followed the following steps to install the stable version (1.8.0) open jdk in Cent OS.

1. `sudo -i`
2. `yum install sudo -y`
3. `sudo yum update`
4. `su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"`
5. `sudo alternatives --config java (or) sudo alternatives --config javac`

However, I see only the following folders in /usr/lib/jvm/ where JDK folder is missing

1. java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64 (inside only jre folder is available)
2. jre
3. jre-1.8.0
4. jre-1.8.0-openjdk
5. jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64
6. jre-openjdk

The following not found and unable to verify JDK

1. /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/bin/
2. /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/bin/java

**Observation**:

1. java is found in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/jre/bin/

**Question**:

1. Is JDK cannot be installed on Cent OS?
2. If java found in JRE should be used, why java placed under JRE folder
   instead of java folder as we usually see during java installation in olden days
3. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correctly package for jdk is this one:

> java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK 8 Development Environment

`dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`